# psycopg2 - how to always cast non-string value to string

Tags: python, psycopg2

psycopg2's doc has an instruction on how to cast a specific type to a different type:

> Psycopg converts decimal/numeric database types into Python Decimal objects. Can I have float instead?
>   You can register a customized adapter for PostgreSQL decimal type:

```
    DEC2FLOAT = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
        psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values,
        'DEC2FLOAT',
        lambda value, curs: float(value) if value is not None else None)
    psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DEC2FLOAT)
```

But my data will have a mixture of str, float, integer, decimal, date type, etc. How do i tell psycopg2 to cast any non string value to string? I don't want to register a customized adapter everytime I encounter a new type because my query could change.
I hope I make the situation clear enough. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could delete all the typecasters and receive everything in the postgres string representation:

```
import psycopg2

for k in psycopg2.extensions.string_types.keys():
    del psycopg2.extensions.string_types[k]

cnn = psycopg2.connect('')
cur = cnn.cursor()
cur.execute("select 1::int, now()::timestamp, 'hello'::text")
cur.fetchone()
('1', '2011-12-19 16:50:11.396855', 'hello')
```

Comment: I have a question though, why not do psycopg2.extensions.string_types.clear() ? is there a difference?

Comment: No, actually `clear()` would have done just fine: it's a simple dictionary.

Comment: awesome.  i used it to modify the connection for txpostgres, works like a champ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe enough call `str(object)` or take field str like `object.__str__`

Comment: the query will return a list of lists: `[[bool, str, int],[float,datetime,]...]` If i use str(obj) I will need to iterate everything in the big list. I don't think it's efficient.